# ReactJS Jest enzyme unit testing axios.get() axios.post()

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

My code is like

```js
constructor(props) {
  super();
  this.state = {
    isLoading: true,
    questionsData: [],
    studyCategoryList: [],
    studyList: [],
    filteredStudyList: [],
    selectedStudyCategory: "0",
    selectedStudy: "0",
    filterData: [],
    deleteQuestionIndex: 0   
  };
}
```

In constructor, I am initializing the state, and I have written below method for dropdowns data

```js
componentDidMount() {
  this._isMounted = true;
  axios
    .get(url + "getAllQuestionsDropdownValues")
    .then((response) => {
      this.setState({ studyCategoryList: response.data[0],studyList: response.data[1] });
      // this.setState({ studyList: response.data[1] });
      // this.setState({ isLoading: false });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      // this.setState({ isLoading: false });
    });

  this.getQuestionsData(this.state.selectedStudyCategory, this.state.selectedStudy);

  const selectAll = "0";
  this.state.selectedStudyCategory = selectAll;
  this.state.selectedStudy = selectAll;
}
```

Based on dropdown selection, posting the dropdown selected data and getting the filtered data from database. find the below post method for it.

```js
getQuestionsData = (scid, sid) => {
  this.setState({ isLoading: true });
  axios.post(`${url}getQuestionList`, { studycategoryid: scid, studyid: sid })
    .then((response) => {
      this.setState({ questionsData: response.data, filterData: response.data });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      this.setState({ isLoading: false });
    });
}
```

When writing the uint test cases with axios, I couldn't able to write test cases with jest enzyme on axios get and post methods.

Please provide complete example to achieve it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try and what did not work? Please, list exact errors, not describe them. *Please provide complete example to achieve it* - SO isn't code writing service. It's easier and more useful for other users to suggest a fix for your code than to write it from scratch.

Comment: I recommend `axios-mock-adapter`

Answer (score 0):

In order to test axios requests, you need to use the [`jest-mock-axios` library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-mock-axios).

```
> npm i --save-dev jest-mock-axios
```

The docs state clearly the steps to follow, that are (partially) copied here:

Next you need to setup a manual Jest mock for Axios:

- create `__mocks__` directory in your project root
- inside this new directory create a files named `axios.js`
- copy & paste the following snippets to `axios.js` file

```js
// ./__mocks__/axios.js
import mockAxios from 'jest-mock-axios';
export default mockAxios;
```

And then, here is a basic test file example to test your `axios.post` request:

```js
import mockAxios from 'jest-mock-axios';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import YourComponent from '../src/YourComponent';
 
afterEach(() => {
    // cleaning up the mess left behind the previous test
    mockAxios.reset();
});
 
it('YourComponent should get data', () => {
    mockAxios.mockResponse({ data : <your_mocked_data> });
 
    // using the component, which should make a server response
    let clientMessage = 'client is saying hello!';

    mount(<YourComponent>);
 
    // since `get` method is a spy, we can check if the server request was correct
    // a) the correct method was used (get)
    // b) went to the correct web service URL ('/<your_service_url>/')
    // c) if the payload was correct (<your_mocked_data>)
    expect(mockAxios.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/<your_service_url>/', {data: <your_mocked_data> });
});
```

The `post` test should look the same.

Check the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-mock-axios) for more details !